# How do I specify more than one category?

Tags: categories, comments, hacks

I am excluding comments from specific categories. However, when I try to exclude more than one, it doesn't work.

This works: `<?php if (!in_category('7')) comments_template(); ?>`

This does not work:

```
<?php if (!in_category('7 , 9')) comments_template(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (!in_category('7')) comments_template(); ?>
<?php if (!in_category('9')) comments_template(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using category slugs instead of ids. Please try something like this:

```
if ( ! in_category( array( 'bunnies', 'tacos', 'banana-pirates' ) ) ) {
    comments_template();
}
```

Comment: lolbbq that is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Put the IDs into an array, like this:

`<?php if (!in_category(array(7, 9))) comments_template(); ?>`